# JavaScript changes to css are not being being kept

Tags: javascript, css, dom

The `do_game` function is supposed to change the color of the body permanently, but instead it happens for an instant and goes back the way that it was.

```
let do_game = ()=>{
    let colorArray = ["blue","cyan","gray","green","magenta","orange",
    ,"white","yellow"]
    // let target = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)];
    let target = colorArray[0];
    console.log(target);
    let input = validateValue(colorArray);

    if(input === false){
        return false;
    }

    if(compareInputToTarget(input, target) == false){
        return false;
    }

    let body = document.getElementById("body");
    body.style.background = target;

    // window.backgroundTarget = target;
    return target;
}

(function(){
    document.getElementById("ok").addEventListener("click", do_game);
    // body.style.background = window.backgroundTarget;
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce based on the code you provided.  The following adjustment to your code demonstrates a permanent change of color.

```js
function validateValue() {
  return true;
}

function compareInputToTarget(input, target) {
  return true;
}


let do_game = ()=>{
    let colorArray = ["blue","cyan","gray","green","magenta","orange",
    ,"white","yellow"]
    // let target = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)];
    let target = colorArray[0];
    console.log(target);
    let input = validateValue(colorArray);

    if(input === false){
        return false;
    }

    if(compareInputToTarget(input, target) == false){
        return false;
    }

    let body = document.getElementById("body");
    body.style.background = target;

    // window.backgroundTarget = target;
    return target;
}

(function(){
    document.getElementById("ok").addEventListener("click", do_game);
    // body.style.background = window.backgroundTarget;
})()
```

```html
<body id="body">
<button id="ok">OK</button>
</body>
```